# A child component re-renders when props has link to a click handler - how to stop it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I pass the click handler to the child component and it causes re-rendering every time when a parent component changes. Can't figure out how to stop it. Without the "handleClick" prop the child component doesn't re-render.

```
function SubComponent({ handleClick }) {
  console.log("component render");
  return <div onClick={handleClick}>SubComponent</div>;
}

const MemoizedSubComponent = memo(SubComponent);

export default function App() {
  console.log('app render')
  const [test, setTest] = useState(1);
  const onHandleClick = () => {
    console.log(1)
};
const increment = ()=>{
  setTest(test+1)
};
  return (
    <><button onClick={increment}>Increment {test}</button>
    <MemoizedSubComponent
        handleClick={onHandleClick}
    /></>
);
}
```

Working code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-https-6hl04z

How to test:

- click the "IncrementN" button in the App component and see the console: it will say "rerender component" every time when you click.
- if you remove or comment the handleClick={onHandleClick} line in the App, there is no re-rendering every time but only when some data props change like tab.

How to prevent this re-rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React will re-render your component when it detects changes in props.

You have defined a function `testoClick` in App, and passed it to `TodoList`.

`testoClick` is created every time `App` renders, and so React detects that props has changed, and will re-render `TodoList`. This is expected.

You can use the `useCallback` hook to memoise the `testoClick` handler. `useCallback` will return the same object reference so long as the dependencies have not changed.

By returning a memoized `testoClick`, React will not detect any changes in props, and therefore will not re-render `TodoList`

```js
const testoClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log(1);
  },[]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help, the child component still re-renders every time when Increment button clicks. I've simplified the example and added useCallback there, please look at the updated codebox.

Comment: @mimic, It worked for me. I think you just forgot to add the dependency array

Comment: @VictorSantizo you are right, I did!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using an arrow method directly, the method is not memoized. This would create a new instance every time the component is rendered (with new props object with a new reference even though it looks the same on code).

Wrapping the testoClick method with an useCallback hook would help resolve your problem.

```
const testoClick = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(1);
}, []);
```

Tip for optimization: Move all the inline arrow methods to useCallback wrapped methods. Example below:

```
const someMethod = useCallback(() => setTest(test + 1)), [test])

<button onClick={someMethod}>Increment{test}</button>
```